# Outlook 2010 crashes when viewing mail with Japanese text

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010

I have a user whose Outlook 2010 (32-bit) client crashes when attempting to view mail with Japanese text in the body. The client crashes both when I use the reading pane and when I try to open the message without the reading pane. The user is running 64-bit Windows 7 Professional.

This is what showed up in the Application log at first:

> Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 14.0.6126.5003, time stamp: 0x505b1685
>
> Faulting module name: riched20.dll, version: 14.0.6015.1000, time stamp: 0x4d1933c2
>
> Exception code: 0xc0000005
>
> Fault offset: 0x0001dcc0
>
> Faulting process id: 0xecc
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01cdc6f530bbbd29
>
> Faulting application path: C:\PROGRA~2\MIF5BA~1\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\riched20.dll
>
> Report Id: 12c33f72-32f2-11e2-ad30-f0def1549eda

So I renamed riched20.dll and repaired Office. It got replaced, but the log entry for each crash looks now like this:

> Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 14.0.6126.5003, time stamp: 0x505b1685
>
> Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
>
> Exception code: 0xc000041d
>
> Fault offset: 0x745f4c4f
>
> Faulting process id: 0x17b8
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01cdc795daf5b339
>
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE
>
> Faulting module path: unknown
>
> Report Id: abc57e29-3389-11e2-86b6-f0def1549eda

I've tried:

- Rebooting (of course)
- Repairing Office
- Removing and reinstalling Office
- Running Outlook in safe mode
- Removing the antivirus client temporarily

No luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: What type of PST file is the client using. Is it an old one from the 97-2003 days?

Comment: It's not in a PST, it's in the inbox, i.e. cached in outlook.ost.

Comment: Ran out of time, I just reimaged the machine. No idea what the problem was, maybe some language files were missing or corrupted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RichEd20.DLL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291651) is the library which enables Rich Text Editing within Outlook.  Based on exception code 0xc000041d (unhandled exception in user callback, maybe a null pointer exception), it's safe to say the repair failed spectacularly probably by not linking the new library correctly.

The initial exception, 0xc0000005, is an access violation within the library.  This leads me to believe that there may have been a corruption in the language display support for the OS itself rather than only Outlook.  Re-imaging a machine would solve this of course...  An alternative is to "trick" the machine into re-initializing its language display settings by changing its [locale](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-can-i-get-chinesejapanese-characters-to/fdb1f1da-b868-40d1-a4a4-7acadff4aafa)

As an aside, if this comes up with a character set that's not natively supported within windows, a re-install of the Language Interface Pack or [LIP](http://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/installation/downloads/Pages/windows_7_language_interface_packs.aspx) may solve the issue as well.

Comment: Sounds like that might have been it.